# Performance impact of vararg in Java

Tags: java, generics, jvm

I have few overloaded method, which I can replace with *vararg*, but these are getting called numerous times.

I just wanted to know its impact. I assume jvm creates an array from the parameters at runtime, so theoretically there must be some impact, not sure practically will it impact or not!

Comment: Do you have performance issues? _early optimization is the root of all evil_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one and only answer that makes sense here: go and **measure** yourself. Yes, you are correct - varargs are syntactic sugar - and the compiler creates arrays under the hood. So, yes - there is a certain performance impact.

But if that *penalty* really matters to you depends **solely** on your requirements and your context.

I *think* (opinion) here: when this really impacts the perceived *performance* of your application - then you probably have **other** problems already.